# How to insert field with html onclick event?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need help, if an image is clicked, then in the database will insert 1 value.
Example, if I click `code` then in the database will insert `1` in `number_of_click`. Then if I click `code` again, it will insert `2` etc.
But I am using Laravel 5.2, so I am so confused

### View

```
<a onclick="addAds()" id="add" target="_blank" href="{{$ads1->link}}"><img src="{{URL::asset('Gambar')}}/{{$ads1->image}}" alt=""/></a>
```

Comment: General idea is to use AJAX, when the image is click send an AJAX call to the backend controller to perform the addition. It would be good if you post what have you tried.

Comment: but, i don't understand to call the controller on ajax, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

```js
click = 0;
function addClick(){
 click++;
  $.ajax({
    url: "Your-URL",
    type: "post",
    data: {'click': click},
    success: function (response){
      if(response){
        alert("Click has been inserted.");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addClick();">Click</a>
```

In Your Your-Url Page
handle this request and insert into the database as per your requirement.

For more information: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm

Comment: Instead of incrementing the click at front-end don't you think its a better idea to increment it at the controller?